# android UserRecoverableAuthException not throwed

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using Google APIs Java Client to get files from google drive. In the [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_with_the_google_apis_java_client) advise to catch UserRecoverableAuthException to determine user login.

```
credintial.setSelectedAccountName(eMail);
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new AndroidJsonFactory();
Drive drive = new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), jsonFactory, credintial)
        .setApplicationName(mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)).build();

Drive.Files.List request = drive.files().list();
request.setFields("items(id,mimeType,title,downloadUrl)");
FileList result = request.execute();

token = credintial.getToken();
```

But line `token = credintial.getToken();` doesnt throw this exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your code credintial or credential? It should be credential